# What is source of this verse (त्रिया चरित्रं, पुरुषस्य भाग्यम;)?

Tags: scripture, identification-request, reference-request

In which scripture, this verse is present.:

> नृपस्य चित्तं, कृपणस्य वित्तम; मनोरथाः दुर्जनमानवानाम्।
> त्रिया चरित्रं, पुरुषस्य भाग्यम; देवो न जानाति कुतो मनुष्यः।।
>
> The mind of the king, The wealth of the miser;  The desires of the wicked humans. The three characters (Sat, Raj, Tam), The fate of a man; Even the gods does not know, Then, how can a human-being know.

And who has said this verse ?
Is it from Mahabharata ?

Answer (score 3):

The correct and original verse is this -

**राष्ट्रस्य चित्तं कृपणस्य वित्तं मनोरथा: दुर्जनमानुषाणाम्‌।
स्त्रियाश्चरित्रं पुरुषस्य भाग्यं देवो न जानाति कुतो मनुष्यः॥**

**Meaning**: When Gods themselves do not know the mind/thoughts of a nation, the wealth of a miser, the desire of a wicked human being, the character of a woman and the fate of a man, then how can a human being know?

[image]

It is from *Subhaashita Ratna BhaanDaagaara* which is a compilation of nearly 10,000 subhaashitaas (epigrams), originally credited to a *kashinath Sharma* - we dont know when he did it (probably in the last 1000 years), but we know that it was first printed into a book in 1802. Since then several versions have been published, with the 1952 version in which an explanation was provided for certain verses or chapters by a Nārāyaṇa Rāma Ācārya.

This particular verse above also later appears in a Gujarati work called *Virkshetra Ni Sundari* in 1948 by *Thakkur Narayan* -

[image]